# isValid in zend framework form returns FALSE

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have zend framework controller.
In init method i create a form and fill the drop-down box with

```
$form = new FORM_NAME();
$form->getElement('ZdGroup')->addMultiOptions($zendesk_groups);
```

then in action i check

```
$formData = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
        ...
}
```

but `isValid()` returns `FALSE`
if I delete this line 
`$form->getElement('ZdGroup')->addMultiOptions($zendesk_groups);`
it return `TRUE`.

I don't understand why, does anybody have an idea?

Comment: We need your `FORM_NAME()` class to know what your form is doing.

Comment: Maybe that element is set to required at FORM_NAME. $element->setRequired (true)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To answer the question of 'why', have you dumped the form error messages?

```
$form->getMessages(); //error messages
$form->getErrors(); //error codes
$form->getErrorMessages(); //any custom error messages
```

That might at least give you a better idea of 'why'.

Comment: sometimes using file input without setting enctype on form , cause this problem .

Comment: umm.. are you sure? messages is empty and errors/errorMessage does not even exist as a functino.

Comment: @Blauhirn This question is 4 years old, pretty sure this answer is for ZF1.

Comment: If i want for this in ZF3 then ?